# How do you put XML Comments on Action<int> in c#

Tags: c#

I have some action events like this.

```
///<summary>
///Event thrown when the score changes
///</summary>
public Action<int> OnScoreChanged = delegate {};
```

I can put a xml comment with the basic summery block. but i don't know how to add good documentation for the Int. This event is really simple and self explanatory, but in the idea of trying to get good habits for when the event might have a less obvious variables.

Is it considered "best practice" to just put the explanation of the variable in the summery or is there something similar to 'param' that will work without a variable name?

Thanks

Comment: If you need more detailed information, it might make more sense to declare a delegate instead. Or this could be an actual *event* with an event arguments object that you then document properly.

Comment: "This event is really simple and self explanatory" - What does the `int` represent? It's quite obvious that this event happens after the score of something changed, but the meaning of the `int` there is not so obvious.

Comment: What about using `<remarks>`? You can write additional informations in this section, explaining what the `int` argument is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `<param>` for this (you may use a name like param1 or something):

```
<param name="name">description</param>
```

More informations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/param

Comment: This will not be picked up for properties by editors though.